# Shell Script Segmentation Fault

Tags: php, shell

Hi I have a shell script which should run based on the return of php code:

```
x=1
while [[ "$x" != 5 ]] 
do
  echo "Welcome $x"
  php test.php
  x=$?
done
```

And the php code

```
echo "Testdfdf test".PHP_EOL;
exit(4);
```

So I want whenever I get 5 from php to quit the loop.

But I get sometimes:

```
./myshell: line 7: 20529 Segmentation fault      php test.php
```

Should it loop without problem?

Comment: Enable core dumps with ulimit; run the script; when you look at the core file, it will tell you which process resulted in its creation -- most likely the PHP interpreter, making this not a bash problem; you can then generate a stack trace from the core dump to report to the relevant party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because of this error which affects both Ubuntu and Debian... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/343870

Comment: I have the same issue with Debian but not in CentOS

Answer (score 1):

It should and it does, but no clue about why php is ending with a segfault.

Answer (score 1):

your shell while loop will loop forever, as your php script returns 4 to shell, and your while loop checks for !=5. which means the condition is not going to be met. what actually is it you are wanting to do? unless necessary, i would advise to do everything with php (or shell) , but try not to intermingle both.

Comment: Intermingling both is fully in line with the UNIX ideology of "many small tools"; calling other programs and checking their exit code is, after all, what shell does best. :)

The advantage of pushing everything into PHP is that there wouldn't be a need to start up a new interpreter every cycle of the loop -- certainly a performance enhancement, albeit perhaps one with an impact on correctness (if the PHP [ab]uses global variables).